# Binary addition program returns message 'takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)'

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to create a program that adds two binary numbers but the program only returns 'takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)' and I don't know what this means. Here is my code:

```
def binValid(binNumber):
    valid=1
    for x in binNumber :
        if(x != "0" and x != "1"):
           valid = 0
    return valid
def addBin(binA,binB):
    if ((binValid(binA)) and (binValid(binB))):
        maxLen = max(len(binA),len(binB))
        binA = binA.zfill(maxLen)
        binB = binB.zfill(maxLen)
        carry = 0
        answer = ""
        for i in range ((maxLen-1),-1,-1):
            ans = (int(binA[i])+int(binB[i])+carry)% 2
            carry = (int(binA[i])+int(binB[i])+carry)// 2
            answer = str(ans) + answer
        answer = str(carry) + answer
        answer = answer.lstrip("0")
        return answer
    else:
         return("this is not a binary number")
```

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: The error message means you're calling a two-argument function with one argument. The traceback should have a line showing exactly where you're doing that. Take a look.